# Why is there a "0" value remaining in the list, despite code that removes "0" values?

Tags: java

I am working through sample questions for the Computer Science A exam and cannot figure out why the correct answer is correct on the following problem.

Consider the following method.

```
public static void mystery(List<Integer> nums)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < nums.size(); k++)
    {
         if (nums.get(k).intValue() == 0)
         {
              nums.remove(k);
         }
    }
}
```

Assume that a List values initially contains the following Integer values.
[0, 0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0]
What will values contain as a result of executing mystery(values)?

The correct answer showing is : [0, 4, 2, 5, 3]

Why does the first 0 remain in the list?

Comment: When k = 1, you've removed the 0 at position 0. So now your list is 0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0. When I took the AB exam (a very long time ago) I found it easier to write out what the `nums` list would look like after each iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: To correct the index, you could write `nums.remove(k--);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `0` remains because that was really the second `0` in `nums`.

When `k` is `0`, the test succeeds and `remove(0)` is called, removing the first index.  That shifts all the other elements down, so that the list is now `[0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0]`.  But then `k` is incremented to `1`, so the second `0` (now at index `0`) is skipped and not removed.

The other `0` values are removed successfully, just as the first `0` is removed successfully.  This code skips only the *second* of two consecutive `0` values.  This would be a bug, assuming that the code is supposed to remove *all* `0` values.

Comment: And if you are removing items when you step through a Collection of any type, you should probably start at the end and work back toward zero.

Answer (score 0):

The answer already given by @rgettman is correct.  However, I'd like to add that this is a particular example of a common issue - that of modifying a sequence (collection, whatever) while iterating (indexing, whatever) through it.  You need to understand the effect that the modification will have on the in-progress iteration.  And sometimes the effect is formally given as "undefined", i.e., you don't want to do it.

For Java, the Iterator<> class has a remove() method that safely removes the current element.  If you actually wanted to remove all zeroes from your List<>, rather than just explaining what is happening in the test question, then Iterator would be one way to go about it.